# SSL Certificate for remix-ide environment

Tags: remix

I have installed remix-ide in my azure vm.Through http:/publicip:8080 i can able to access the remix-ide environment but i dont know how to make it as a https and where to mentioned the ssl certificate path.Please help me to do this